# Using a recursive binary search in an InsertInOrder

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search, insertion-sort

I'm reading in a text file of unsorted numbers

```
static void insertInOrder( int[] arr, int cnt, int newVal )
    {
        int belongs = -( bSearch( arr, 0, arr.length-1, newVal)) - 1;
        {
            for ( int i = cnt; i >= belongs+1 ; --i)
            {
                arr[i] = arr[i-1];
            }

        arr[belongs] = newVal;
    }

    }

    // We do not need to pass in count. The incoming lo and hi define the range
    public static int bSearch(int[] a, int lo, int hi, int key)
    {
    int mid = (lo+hi)/2;
    if(lo>hi)
        return -1;
    else if (a[mid]==key)
        return mid;
    else if (a[mid]<key)
        return bSearch(a, mid+1, hi, key);
    else
        return bSearch(a, lo, mid-1, key);
    }
```

The binary search is working, but my insertinorder isn't putting the numbers in ascending order and I can't figure out why. It's just printing the list out backwards. And this has to be done using a recursive binary search in an insertinorder.

Comment: Can you explain what cnt and newVal represent in the method insertInOrder?

Comment: Can you explain what one call of `insertInOrder` is supposed to do with its arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied the latest code in to the question ???.

One obvious problem is:

```
int belongs = -( bSearch( arr, 0, arr.length-1, newVal)) - 1;
```

the method **bSearch** returns -1 when a value is not found in the array. This will give an insertion point of -2 when newValue is not found. You need to change **bSearch** to return both wether the item was found and the position. Two options

1. Create (and return) a new class

   ```
   private class FoundResult {
       boolean found = true;
       int position;
   }
   ```
2. When not found; return -hi-1
   i.e. in bSearch some thing like:

   ```
   if(lo>hi)
      return -hi-1;
   ```

---

For option 1, the code will be roughly (i have not tested this):

```
static void insertInOrder( int[] arr, int cnt, int newVal )     {

    int belongs = bSearch( arr, 0, arr.length-1, newVal)).position ;
    for ( int i = cnt; i >= belongs+1 ; --i) {
       arr[i] = arr[i-1];
    }

    arr[belongs] = newVal;
}

// We do not need to pass in count. The incoming lo and hi define the range
public static FoundResult bSearch(int[] a, int lo, int hi, int key)
{
int mid = (lo+hi)/2;
FoundResult ret;
if(lo>hi) {
    ret = new FoundResult();
    ret.found = false;
    ret.position = hi;
    return ret;
} else if (a[mid]==key) {
    ret = new FoundResult();
    ret.position = hi;
    return ret;
} else if (a[mid]<key) {
    return bSearch(a, mid+1, hi, key);
} else {
    return bSearch(a, lo, mid-1, key);
}
```

---

For option 2 the code is roughly:

```
static void insertInOrder( int[] arr, int cnt, int newVal )     {

    int belongs = bSearch( arr, 0, arr.length-1, newVal)) ;
    if (belongs < 0) {
        belongs  = -1 - belongs ;
    }
    for ( int i = cnt; i >= belongs+1 ; --i) {
       arr[i] = arr[i-1];
    }

    arr[belongs] = newVal;
}

// We do not need to pass in count. The incoming lo and hi define the range
public static int bSearch(int[] a, int lo, int hi, int key)
{
int mid = (lo+hi)/2;
FoundResult ret;
if(lo>hi) {
    return - hi - 1;
} else if (a[mid]==key) {
    return hi;
} else if (a[mid]<key) {
    return bSearch(a, mid+1, hi, key);
} else {
    return bSearch(a, lo, mid-1, key);
}
```

Comment: It does work, but we're not supposed to create any other classes. We're supposed to do it with just the bsearch and insertinorder.

Comment: you could use option 2; return -hi-1 from bSearch instead of -1

Comment: I have updated the answer for option 2 (returning an integer value), In this case you are using the return for 2 different purposes which is not ideal (and could lead to confusion when other people maintain your code).

Comment: For some reason it's giving me an array index out of bounds exception and I can't find out where the problem is.

Comment: I did not test the code at all; the line belongs  = 1 - belongs ; should be belongs  =  -1 - belongs ; will update the answer